# Setting onclick button color while waiting

Tags: android, buttonclick

I have an onclick listener for a button. Is there any way when I click the button, make the text change color until my new activity is brought up?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setTextColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29) on a button, too, as it extends a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) (you can Ctrl+F on that page for "setTextColor()" to find the reference, it's under "Inherited XML Attributes"). So when the button is pressed you would use `button.setTextColor(newColorInt);` and when the loading is done `button.setTextColor(oldColorInt);`